# Круг с тенью SVG

Tags: css, svg, svg-filter

Подскажите, хочу на SVG сделать круг с такой тенью.
Круг делать с обычной обводкой умею.

Мне нужно объяснить как одно кольцо с тенью делать

По умолчанию тень не видна, а при наведении нужно показывать тень

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
html, body, svg {
  width: 100vmin;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

circle {
  fill: white;
  stroke: silver;
}

g:hover circle {
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 2px silver);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-80 -80 160 160">
  <g>
    <circle r="64" />
    <circle r="48" />
    <circle r="32" />
    <circle r="16" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

> Подскажи, пожалуйста, а как сделать, когда наводишь на бОльший элемент и идёшь внутрь, наведение остаётся у большого элемента?

```css
html, body, svg {
  width: 100vmin;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

circle {
  fill: white;
  stroke: silver;
}

g:hover circle:not(circle:hover ~ circle) {
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 2px silver);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-80 -80 160 160">
  <g>
    <circle r="64" />
    <circle r="48" />
    <circle r="32" />
    <circle r="16" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

или так:

```css
html, body, svg {
  width: 100vmin;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

circle {
  fill: white;
  stroke: silver;
}

g:hover circle {
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 2px silver);
}

circle:hover ~ circle {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-80 -80 160 160">
  <g>
    <circle r="64" />
    <circle r="48" />
    <circle r="32" />
    <circle r="16" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Просто и со вкусом. Голосую за.

Comment: Подскажи, пожалуйста, а как сделать, когда наводишь на бОльший  элемент и идёшь внутрь, наведение остаётся у большого элемента? Я не понимаю

Comment: Твой ответ привёл меня к моему ответу, отмечу как более релевантный

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, дополнил.

Comment: @Qwertiy нифига себе! А я думал, что нельзя обращаться к соседям выше! Я хотел понять, как сделать такую возможность, чтобы обращаться к соседям выше, но не получилось

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, вот скоро `:has` подвезут и вообще можно будет вытворять)))

Comment: @Qwertiy а когда появится? Я сейчас потестировал, оказывается, плохо работает это. Решил сделать контейнер грид с отступами и обращаться к элементам выше. При наведении на пустой отступ, все элементы выделяются. Потому что на контейнер навели и элемент в контейнере не наведён. Плюс, если контейнер сделать с пустым местом и наводить на контейнер, то также все элементы выделяются.

Comment: `.item-wrapper:hover .item:not(.item:hover ~ .item)` - вот такой селектор при включении в браузере `:hover` на `.item-wrapper` выделяет сразу все элементы

Comment: А не знаешь, нету ли черновика о селекторе, как ~, только для верхних соседей?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, я ж сказал - `:has` - в хроме вроде уже работает. А зачем тебе?

Answer (score 2):

> Мне нужно объяснить как одно кольцо с тенью делать

Решил немного усложнить задачу: кнопка в виде одиночного круга, где тень будет создавать эффект нажатия. Для этого надо, чтобы при наведении светлая и темная тень менялись сторонами.

Для этого меняется всего один параметр `elevation` в фильтре отвечающем за направление света

`<feDistantLight azimuth="225" elevation="145"/>`

```css
.btn {
filter:url(#filterUp);
fill:#919191;
stroke:#919191;
stroke-width:2;
}
.btn:hover {
filter:url(#filterDown);
fill:#919191;
stroke:#888888;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="300">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filterUp">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="8" result="blur1"/>
      <feSpecularLighting result="specOut" in="blur1" specularConstant="1.2" specularExponent="12" lighting-color="#fff">
         <feDistantLight azimuth="225" elevation="45"/> 
      </feSpecularLighting>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="result"/>
      <feComposite operator="atop" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>

    <filter id="filterDown">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="8" result="blur1"/>
      <feSpecularLighting result="specOut" in="blur1" specularConstant="1.2" specularExponent="12" lighting-color="#fff">
         <feDistantLight azimuth="225" elevation="145"/> 
      </feSpecularLighting>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut" operator="arithmetic" k1="1" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="result"/>
      <feComposite operator="atop" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
 
 </defs>
     <rect id="back" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#d3d3d3" /> 
    
      <circle class="btn" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" /> 
      <circle class="btn" cx="250" cy="100" r="50" />

</svg>
```

Для задачи, когда нужно сделать такую тень для нескольких кругов, такой набор фильтров не сработает, так как круги расположены друг над другом.

### Вариант тени для нескольких кругов

Получилось, что свет падает справа и слева при наведении курсора, создавая наружную и внутреннюю тень, тем самым круги получаются объемными при наведении курсора.

```css
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}

:root {
    --easing: cubic-bezier(0.87, 0.08, 0.23, 0.91);
    --duration: 0.8s;
    --gray: gray;
}

#app {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circle-gray {
    fill:none;
   stroke:#d8d8d8;
    stroke-width: 4;
    
}

#svg1:hover {
filter: url(#drop-shadow); 

}
#svg1:hover  .circle-gray   {
stroke:white;
atroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id='app'>
    <svg id="svg1" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
        <defs>
 
<filter id="drop-shadow" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" x="-50%" y="-50%" height="200%" width="200%">
<!-- Возьмите исходную альфу, сместите ее по углу/расстоянию и размойте по размеру. -->

<feOffset id="offset" in="SourceAlpha" dx="6" dy="-0.28" result="SA-offset"/>
<feGaussianBlur id="blur" in="SA-offset" stdDeviation="8" result="SA-o-blur"/>

<!-- Примените контур, используя преобразование цветовой кривой на альфа-канале и вырезав результат на входе. -->

<feComponentTransfer in="SA-o-blur" result="SA-o-b-contIN">
  <feFuncA id="contour" type="table" tableValues="0 .95 0 .75 0"/>
</feComponentTransfer> 

<feComposite operator="in" in="SA-o-blur" in2="SA-o-b-contIN" result="SA-o-b-cont"/>

<!-- Отрегулируйте спред, умножив альфа на постоянный коэффициент --> <feComponentTransfer in="SA-o-b-cont" result="SA-o-b-c-sprd">
  <feFuncA id="spread-ctrl" type="linear" slope="1.7"/>
</feComponentTransfer>

<!-- Отрегулируйте цвет и непрозрачность, добавив фиксированные смещения и множитель непрозрачности. -->
<feColorMatrix id="recolor" in="SA-o-b-c-sprd" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.55 0" result="SA-o-b-c-s-recolor"/>

<!-- Сгенерируйте достаточно зернистый входной шум с baseFrequency примерно от 0,5 до 2,0. И добавьте шум с множителями k1 и k2, сумма которых равна 1. -->
<feTurbulence result="fNoise" type="fractalNoise" numOctaves="6" baseFrequency="1.98"/>
<feColorMatrix in="fNoise" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 7 -3" result="clipNoise"/>
<feComposite id="noisemix" operator="arithmetic" in="SA-o-b-c-s-recolor" in2="clipNoise" k1="1" k2="1" k3="0"  result="SA-o-b-c-s-r-mix"/>

<!-- Слияние тени с оригиналом -->
<feMerge>
  <feMergeNode in="SA-o-b-c-s-r-mix"/>
  <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
</feMerge>
</filter> 
           
        </defs>
        
        
        <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="180" class="circle-gray" />
        <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="140" class="circle-gray" />
        <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="95" class="circle-gray" />
        <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="50" class="circle-gray" />
             
        
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Но у тебя получается везде обводка. А у кругов на картинке с левой верхней части вообще нету тени

Comment: Добавил ответ, как пример, что я пытаюсь получить

Comment: Добавил ответ, получилось

Comment: @МихаилКамахин **По умолчанию тень не видна, а при наведении нужно показывать тень**. У тебя до сих пор наоборот - по умолчанию тень видна, а при наведении исчезает. Ты принял ответ Qwertiy, где всё работает, как ты хотел. И это правильно.

Comment: Неправильно написал, что я хочу. У Qwertiy не работает так. Нужно, при наведении мыши и идя в круг, чтобы наведение оставалось. При такой реализации SVG как у него это невозможно, потому что нету в CSS селектора, который может при наведении обращаться к соседям взади (к соседям спереди можно - ~)

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Что жирным написано в моем комментарии процитировано из твоего вопроса

Comment: Да, всё правильно, ошибился во время написания вопроса

Answer (score 2):

Мне нужно сделать что-то типа такого, но только наоборот, при наведении на края и идя внутрь, тени с колец уходят.
Я понимаю как на CSS писать такое только
(Чтобы увеличить все круги, нужно увеличить CSS переменную --sizeStart).
По правде, получается какая-то жесть. Чтобы так работало наведение, как нужно, нужно круги вкладывать друг в друга

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.circle {
    --sizeStart: 70;
    --size: calc( var(--sizeStart) * var(--iEnd) * 1px );
    position: relative;
    width: var(--size);
    height: var(--size);
    z-index: var(--iStart);
}

.circle::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: var(--size);
    height: var(--size);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.circle::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
    position: absolute;
    width: var(--size);
    height: var(--size);
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform-origin: center;
    filter: blur(calc( var(--size) / var(--sizeStart) ));
    transform: scaleX(0.98) scaleY(0.98) translate(3%, 5%);
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.circle:not(:first-child) {
    position: absolute;
    --sizeParent: calc( var(--sizeStart) * (var(--iEnd) + var(--iStart) - 1) * 1px );
    --size2Parent: calc( var(--sizeParent) / 2 );
    top: var(--size2Parent);
    left: var(--size2Parent);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.circle:hover ~ .circle::after {
    opacity: 0;
}

.circle:hover::after {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-wrapper">

  <div class="circle" style="--iEnd: 7; --iStart: 1;">
  </div>

  <div class="circle" style="--iEnd: 6; --iStart: 2;">
  </div>

  <div class="circle" style="--iEnd: 5; --iStart: 3;">
  </div>

  <div class="circle" style="--iEnd: 4; --iStart: 4;">
  </div>

  <div class="circle" style="--iEnd: 3; --iStart: 5;">
  </div>

  <div class="circle" style="--iEnd: 2; --iStart: 6;">
  </div>

  <div class="circle" style="--iEnd: 1; --iStart: 7;">
  </div>
</div>
```

UPD:

А вот рабочий пример уже:
Опять же. Как сделать так на SVG - без понятия, я пытался, изменять последовательность элементов на SVG холсте нельзя, чтобы управлять `z-index` как с `position: absolute` элементами, и чтобы на этих элементах работало наведение. Я пробовал `use`, но это так не работает

```css
* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle__wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  --sizeStart: 100;
  --size: calc( var(--sizeStart) * var(--iStart) * 1px);
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid silver;
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 2px silver);
  transition: filter 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.circle:not(:last-child) {
  --sizeMainParent: calc( var(--sizeStart) * (var(--iEnd) + var(--iStart) - 1) * 1px);
  --sizeMain2Parent: calc( var(--sizeMainParent) / 2);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: var(--iEnd);
  top: 100px;
  top: var(--sizeMain2Parent);
  left: var(--sizeMain2Parent);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.circle:hover~.circle,
.circle:hover {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-wrapper">
  <div class="circle" style="--iStart: 1; --iEnd: 5;"></div>
  <div class="circle" style="--iStart: 2; --iEnd: 4;"></div>
  <div class="circle" style="--iStart: 3; --iEnd: 3;"></div>
  <div class="circle" style="--iStart: 4; --iEnd: 2;"></div>
  <div class="circle" style="--iStart: 5; --iEnd: 1;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Действительно, всё работает наоборот. Плюс за попытку решить самостоятельно.